# How to select multiple count(*) values then group by a specific column

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ssms

I've used SQL for a while but wouldn't say I'm at an advanced level. I've tinkered with trying to figure this out myself to no avail.

I have two tables -  **Transaction** and **TransactionType**:

```
| **TransactionID** | **Name**  | **TransactionTypeID** |
| 1 | Tom  | 1 |
| 2 | Jim | 1 |
| 3 | Mo | 2 |
| 4 | Tom | 3 |
| 5 | Sarah | 4 |
| 6 | Tom | 1 |
| 7 | Sarah | 1 |


| **TransactionTypeID** | **TransactionType** |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
```

**The Transaction.TransactionTypeID** is a Forein Key linked **TransactionType.TransactionTypeID** field.

*Here's what I'd like to achieve:*

I'd like a query (this will be a stored procedure) that returns three columns:

**Name** - the value of the Transaction.Name column.

**NumberOfTypeATransactions** -  the count of the number of all transactions of type 'A' for that person.

**NumberOfNonTypeATransactions** - the count of the number of all transactions that are NOT of type A for that person, i.e. all other transaction types.

So, using the above data as an example, the result set would be:

```
| **Name** | **NumberOfTypeATransactions** | **NumberOfNonTypeATransactions** |
| Tom | 2 | 1 |
| Jim | 1 | 0 |
| Mo | 0 | 1 |
| Sarah | 1 | 1 |
```

I might also need to return the results based on a date period (which will be based on a 'transaction date' column in the Transaction table but I haven't finalized this requirement yet.

Any help in how I can achieve this would be much appreciated. Apologies of the layout of the tables is a bit odd - haven't worked out how to format them properly yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just conditional aggregation with a `join`:

```
select t.name,
       sum(case when tt.TransactionType = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as num_As,
       sum(case when tt.TransactionType <> 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as num_notAs
from transaction t join
     transactiontype tt
     on tt.TransactionTypeID = t.TransactionTypeID
group by t.name;
```